# How do I resolve "System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found" in ASP.Net Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am doing an ASP.NET Core course online. One of the modules requires adding a Razor View to the application. Until I add the Razor view the application runs well. After I add it I get the following runtime error:

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/App/Index.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(IEnumerable`1 originalLocations)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.BrowserLinkMiddleware.ExecuteWithFilterAsync(IHttpSocketAdapter injectScriptSocket, String requestId, HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.BrowserRefreshMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.29\Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.29\System.Net.WebSockets.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.29\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
```

As can be seen in the screenshot the View is in this location:
[image]

I had added the Razor NuGet:
[image]

This is my AppController code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace DutchTreat.Controllers
{
    public class AppController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

This is my Index.cshtml code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dutch Treat: @ViewBag.Title</title>

    <link href="~/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
    <h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
    <div class="product-info">
        <img src="~/img/VanGogh.jpg" />
        <h3>Mug</h3>
        <ul class="product-props">
            <li>Price: $9.99</li>
            <li>Artist: Van Gogh</li>
            <li>Title:</li>
            <li>Description: Self-portrait</li>
        </ul>
        <button id="buyButton">Buy</button>

    </div>

    <div id="theForm">
        <form>
            <label>Your Name:</label>
            <br />
            <input />
            <br />
            <label>Email:</label>
            <br />
            <input type="email" />
            <br />
            <label>Subject:</label>
            <br />
            <input />
            <br />
            <label>Message:</label>
            <br />
            <textarea rows="4"></textarea>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Send Message" />
        </form>
    </div>

    <!--<a href="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.map">lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.map</a>
    <a href="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.map">lib/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.map</a>-->

    <div>
        <div id="loginToggle">Login</div>
        <form class="popup-form">
            <div>
                <label>Username</label>
                <input />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Password</label>
                <input />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <label>Remember me</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />


            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my Startup:

```
using DutchTreat.Controllers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace DutchTreat
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            //app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseEndpoints(cfg =>
                    {
                        cfg.MapControllerRoute("Default",
                                               "/{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                                               new { controller = "App", action = "Index" });

                    });

            //If I understand correctly the bellow is for making an API avaialble without
            //having a webpage
            //app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            //{
            //    endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
            //    {
            //        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            //    });
            //});
        }
    }
}
```

The Index.cshtml properties build action is set to "content":
[image]

I have looked at various solutions to the problem and tried implementing them unsuccessfully. Would appreciate help

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as the error indicates,you should name the floder with **Views** instead of **View**

[image]

Comment: Oh, for gods sake :) I've been staring at it for so long I didnt notice. Thank you! that solved it.